# add new element to an N-level Multidimentional array in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an N-level  Multidimentional array like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 7_cat
        [text] => cat1
        [children] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 9_cat
                        [text] => cat3
                    )

            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 8_cat
        [text] => cat2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 13_cat
        [text] => cat4
    )
)
```

and i have an array of index like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => 0
[1] => children
[2] => 0
[3] => id
)
```

so i want to add a new element in first array in these depth. in this example i want to add a new element in $firstarray[0]['children'][0]['id'].
How can i do it?

thanks alot

Comment: Nothing, i don't know how can do it.i am new in php.

Comment: you need to at least try something dude. At least show us or tell us how you think you should approach the problem. No php needed for that, just your attempt at the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do Like this

Here **$oldArray** is your first array

```
$indexArray=Array
(
[0] => 0
[1] => children
[2] => 0
[3] => id
);

$indexForold=[];
foreach($indexArray as $indx){
         $indexForold=$indexForold[$indx];
}

$oldArray[$indexForold]=$myVal;
```

Comment: thanks, but when i use it $indexForold was null and didn't change any thing.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is, while traversing the array use [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) to keep a reference to the current array element.

- Here `$nArr` is your n-dimensional array and `$indexArr` is your index array.
- And don't forget to replace `<YOUR_VALUE>` with your desired value.

So your code should be like this:

```
$arrLength = count($indexArr);

$tmpArr = null;
$i = 0;
for(; $i < $arrLength - 1; ++$i){
    if($tmpArr == null){
        $tmpArr = &$nArr[$indexArr[$i]];
    }else{
        $tmpArr = &$tmpArr[$indexArr[$i]];
    }
}

$tmpArr[$indexArr[$i]] = <YOUR_VALUE>;

// now display the n-dimensional array

echo "<pre>"; 
print_r($nArr); 
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this...

```
$array = [
    [
        'id' => '7_cat',
        'text' => 'cat1',
        'children' => [
            [
                'id' => '9_cat',
                'text' => 'cat3'
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        'id' => '8_cat',
        'text' => 'cat2'
    ],
    [
        'id' => '13_cat',
        'text' => 'cat4'
    ]
];


$multIndexValue = function (array $indexList, array $searchArray) {
    $result = $searchArray;

    foreach ($indexList as $index) {
        $result = $result[$index];
    }


    return $result;
};


$search = [0, 'children', 0, 'id'];


$result = $multIndexValue($search, $array); // string(5) "9_cat"
```